# Which technology to use for making YouTube like application

Tags: web-applications, video-streaming

I want to create a website something similar t YouTube. It will have large number of videos but yet it should be fast.

Could someone tell me which technologies i should use?

Comment: I think it's known as `Information Technology`, also abbreviated as IT.

Comment: Pardon the previous jag, but the question reads a bit like: "Which technology is used for satellite launching vehicles like the ones NASA or ESA design ?"

Comment: Friends, what would you suggest if i like to have live videos, such as a cricket match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless this is for fun/experience just use YouTube/Vimeo/{InsertExistingVideoHostingSiteHere}

Otherwise...

There are many video encoding/streaming techniques available but a good start would be to to look at encoding video using the flash video encoder to encode to the flv format and then flash itself to play the flv files (flash has many built in player controls etc)

You also need to research different encoding techniques to know what you want e.g. 1/2 pass encoding, de-interlacing, codecs

Comment: Thanks Nick for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look what other uses. Most sites uses Flash/Flex for this today. But Silverlight is also an alternative and maybe JavaFx. And HTML5 is coming with the video-tag.

But today I think Flash/Flex is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is to distribute the content, and you don't want to use an existing service, then a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) like [limelight](http://uk.limelightnetworks.com/index.php) a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You could also wait for [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#video), it will support video embedding.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight or Flash.  If you have experience with .Net do Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody). It starts with HTML5, but if it's not available, falls back to Quicktime. If that's not available, Flash. And if all else fails, users can download the movie.

I haven't worked with it yet, but looks exciting. The good thing is it uses HTML5 which should become a standard in the future. But for people with older browsers, it's still perfectly usable.

Answer (score 0):

so to create a video site like you need to do perticular things like
1. Video conversion to lower format
2. capture screenshot for video thumbnail
3. Capture multiple screenshots or make gif out of it 
4. Convert to lower resolution

I dont think that all these things can be done using single serverside code...you need to take help of different encoding software